# eigenvalue diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Suppose that $B$ is an element of $M_n(F)$ and that every vector in the standard basis is an eigenvector of $B$. Prove that $B$ is a diagonal matrix.

I know that the basic idea involves showing that $\lambda e_j$ cannot have nonzero values outside of the $j$ th row and that $A e_j$ satisfies this if and only if $A$ is diagonal. How would I state this formally?

Comment: Use the formula $$A\left(\sum_{k=1}^n v_k e_k\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n [A]_{ik}v_{k}e_i$$ with $v_{k}=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }k=j\\ 0&\text{ if }k\ne j\end{cases}$

Comment: If $B = (b_{ij})_{ij}$, what does a column vector of $B$ represent? For example, what does the vector $^t(b_{11}, ..., b_{n1})$ represent, if you are aware that a matrix defines a linear map?

Answer (score 0):

$B_{ij} = e_i^TBe_j$.

If $Be_j = \lambda_je_j$, then $B_{ij} = \lambda_j e_i^Te_j$.